# Python: Generate Dictionary From Form Data That Comes In As A Single String

Tags: python, string, dictionary

When working with the ASANA API, a form that is filled out is inserted as a single string under a notes field (sample output below). I am working in a Jupyter Notebook via Anaconda using python version 3.9

My goal would be to create a dict where the form question is the KEY and the answer(s) is the VALUE. ex: `{"Name":"Internal Requestor", "Name of Project": "Dummy Test project"}` etc so that I can ultimately store it as a pandas df. Some of the questions do have multi-part answers. Those answers can be kept as a single key, example: `{"What teams will be involved?": "Content","SEO","Creative","Ops","Pr","Internal"}`

EXAMPLE STRING BELOW

"Name:\nInternal Requestor\n\nName of Project:\nDummy Test Project\n\nWhich Marketing O-Team does this project belong to?:\nIncrease traffic\n\nProject Description:\nThis is a project test to see if we can get the fields from this form into a dataframe\n\nWhat is the strategy driving this project?:\nEfficiency is the name of the game!\n\nWhat is the expected impact of the project?:\nBe more efficient than we currently are\n\nPlease rank size of expected impact (H, M, L):\nHigh\n\nWhat are the project objectives?:\nBe more efficient\nClearer creative direction\neasier to stack rank\n\nHow confident are you this project will meet these objectives?:\nHigh\n\nPlease point the size of this project:\n8\n\nWhat teams will be involved?:\nContent/SEO\nCreative\nOps\nPR\nInternal Comms\nSocial\nDemandGen\nOwner\nGuest\nExternal Stakeholders\n\nIf including external stakeholders, please note below:\nRes Ops\n\nPlease point the external stakeholders expected involvement in the project:\n5\n\nWhich content teams?:\nContent\nSEO\n\nPlease point content's expected involvement in the project:\n5\n\nPlease point SEO's expected involvement in the project:\n5\n\nWhich creative teams?:\nDesign\nCopy\n\nPlease point Design's expected involvement in the project:\n8\n\nPlease point Copy's expected involvement in the project:\n8\n\nWhich Ops Teams?:\nAnalytics\nMartech\n\nPlease point Analytics expected involvement in projects:\n8\n\nPlease point Martech's expected involvement in the project:\n8\n\nPlease point PR's expected involvement in the project:\n1\n\nPlease point Internal Comms expected involvement in the project:\n5\n\nPlease point Social's expected involvement in the project:\n5\n\nPlease point DemandGen's expected involvement in the project:\n3\n\nPlease point Owner's expected involvement in the project:\n8\n\nPlease point Guest's expected involvement in the project:\n1\n\nPlease provide project milestones:\nScoping 9/19 - 9/20\nExecution 9/21 - 9/25\nLaunch 9/31\n\nIs this a hard or soft deadline?:\nHard\n\nWhat is driving this deadline?:\nEfficiency\n\nWhich manager approved this request submission?:\nBilly Bob\n

I attempted to use .splitlines(), but was not sure how to utilize the output to construct a dict from the list it returned (particularly when accounting for the questions that have multiple answers, described above). ** New to StackOverflow as well, can include more details as needed **

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Break the problem up into smaller pieces.

Based on your data, start by splitting by double new lines, then by a single new line.

```
>>> raw = "YOUR LONG STRING"
>>> qa = {}
>>> for group in raw.split('\n\n'):
...   question, answers = group.split('\n', 1)
...   qa[question.rstrip(':')] = answers.splitlines()
...
```

which gives

```
{'How confident are you this project will meet these objectives?': ['High'],
 'If including external stakeholders, please note below': ['Res Ops'],
 'Is this a hard or soft deadline?': ['Hard'],
 'Name': ['Internal Requestor'],
 'Name of Project': ['Dummy Test Project'],
 'Please point Analytics expected involvement in projects': ['8'],
 "Please point Copy's expected involvement in the project": ['8'],
 "Please point DemandGen's expected involvement in the project": ['3'],
 "Please point Design's expected involvement in the project": ['8'],
 "Please point Guest's expected involvement in the project": ['1'],
 'Please point Internal Comms expected involvement in the project': ['5'],
 "Please point Martech's expected involvement in the project": ['8'],
 "Please point Owner's expected involvement in the project": ['8'],
 "Please point PR's expected involvement in the project": ['1'],
 "Please point SEO's expected involvement in the project": ['5'],
...
 'What is the strategy driving this project?': ['Efficiency is the name of the '
                                                'game!'],
 'What teams will be involved?': ['Content/SEO',
                                  'Creative',
                                  'Ops',
                                  'PR',
                                  'Internal Comms',
                                  'Social',
                                  'DemandGen',
                                  'Owner',
                                  'Guest',
                                  'External Stakeholders'],
...
```

if you wanted to hardcode something so that single answers weren't lists, you should decide that yourself, that seems ambiguous.
You should also be careful of duplicate questions, etc.

Comment: Is it possible to put that result in a pandas dataframe? The output appears to align on my end when I utilized what you provided, thank you!

Comment: yes, you can stick many things in pandas.  that's a different question though

Answer (score 0):

If `s` is your string :

```
d = {
    entry.split("\n")[0]: ",".join(entry.split("\n")[1:])
    for entry in s.split("\n\n")
}
```

If you ever have 2 newlines in a row in an answer this won't work, but in that case the string is ambiguous and I don't see what could get around that.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have your string in a file, so if this is not the case just ignore the first row;

```
file_as_string = ''.join(open('yourfile.txt').readlines())

outdict = {}
for i in file_as_string.split('\n\n'):
    s = i.split(':\n')
    outdict[s[0]] = s[1]
```

Results:

```
{'Name': 'Internal Requestor',
 'Name of Project': 'Dummy Test Project',
 'Which Marketing O-Team does this project belong to?': 'Increase traffic',
 'Project Description': 'This is a project test to see if we can get the fields from this form into a dataframe',
 'What is the strategy driving this project?': 'Efficiency is the name of the game!',
 'What is the expected impact of the project?': 'Be more efficient than we currently are',
 'Please rank size of expected impact (H, M, L)': 'High',
 'What are the project objectives?': 'Be more efficient\nClearer creative direction\neasier to stack rank',
 'How confident are you this project will meet these objectives?': 'High',
 'Please point the size of this project': '8',
 'What teams will be involved?': 'Content/SEO\nCreative\nOps\nPR\nInternal Comms\nSocial\nDemandGen\nOwner\nGuest\nExternal Stakeholders',
 'If including external stakeholders, please note below': 'Res Ops',
 'Please point the external stakeholders expected involvement in the project': '5',
 'Which content teams?': 'Content\nSEO',
 "Please point content's expected involvement in the project": '5',
 "Please point SEO's expected involvement in the project": '5',
 'Which creative teams?': 'Design\nCopy',
 "Please point Design's expected involvement in the project": '8',
 "Please point Copy's expected involvement in the project": '8',
 'Which Ops Teams?': 'Analytics\nMartech',
 'Please point Analytics expected involvement in projects': '8',
 "Please point Martech's expected involvement in the project": '8',
 "Please point PR's expected involvement in the project": '1',
 'Please point Internal Comms expected involvement in the project': '5',
 "Please point Social's expected involvement in the project": '5',
 "Please point DemandGen's expected involvement in the project": '3',
 "Please point Owner's expected involvement in the project": '8',
 "Please point Guest's expected involvement in the project": '1',
 'Please provide project milestones': 'Scoping 9/19 - 9/20\nExecution 9/21 - 9/25\nLaunch 9/31',
 'Is this a hard or soft deadline?': 'Hard',
 'What is driving this deadline?': 'Efficiency',
 'Which manager approved this request submission?': 'Billy Bob'}
```